# Keras overfits on one class Cifar-10

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tensorflow, keras

To make all things clear let me show the whole model, which is pretty simple:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10 #much more libraries imported
# simple prerocessing 
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()    
batch_size = 32
num_classes = 10
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train  /= 255
x_test /= 255

def base_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    sgd = SGD(lr = 0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    # Train model

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

cnn_n = base_model()
cnn_n.summary()

# Fit model

cnn = cnn_n.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test,y_test)
                ,shuffle=True, verbose= 
0)
```

As you can see train error and validation doesn't even think to decrease errors

[image: error]

```
sequential_model_to_ascii_printout(cnn_n)
 OPERATION           DATA DIMENSIONS   WEIGHTS(N)   WEIGHTS(%)

               Input   #####     32   32    3
              Conv2D    \|/  -------------------       896     0.1%
                relu   #####     32   32   32
              Conv2D    \|/  -------------------      9248     0.7%
                relu   #####     30   30   32
        MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                       #####     15   15   32
             Dropout    | || -------------------         0     0.0%
                       #####     15   15   32
              Conv2D    \|/  -------------------     18496     1.5%
                relu   #####     15   15   64
              Conv2D    \|/  -------------------     36928     3.0%
                relu   #####     13   13   64
        MaxPooling2D   Y max -------------------         0     0.0%
                       #####      6    6   64
             Dropout    | || -------------------         0     0.0%
                       #####      6    6   64
             Flatten   ||||| -------------------         0     0.0%
                       #####        2304
               Dense   XXXXX -------------------   1180160    94.3%
                relu   #####         512
             Dropout    | || -------------------         0     0.0%
                       #####         512
               Dense   XXXXX -------------------      5130     0.4%
             softmax   #####          10
```

Confusion matrix, model definitely overfitts on the third class:
[image]

y_test contains also other classes:

```
y_test
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 0., 0.]]
```

Why model "see" only 1 class?

PS: I was following this guide: https://blog.plon.io/tutorials/cifar-10-classification-using-keras-tutorial/

Comment: I think the learning rate is high. Reduce it to `0.01` (i.e. `lr = 0.01`) and you will probably see that the training progresses. Please confirm this.

Comment: @today you were right, learning rate was to high;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this CIFAR-10 task can choose the Adam optimization algorithm, SGD convergence speed earlier. And you set the learning rate is too large(you can set lr=0.01 or lr=0.001), will be near the minimum point of shock.This is my code:[CIFAR-10](https://github.com/zwd2016/CIFAR-10/blob/master/CIFAR-cnn.py)

Comment: lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=np.sqrt(0.1),
                               cooldown=0,
                               patience=5,
                               min_lr=0.5e-6)  Nice way is to automatically reduce lr

Comment: @Rocketq Thank you. I think Adam's optimization algorithm is adaptive learning rate, it is based on the specific situation to change the value of the learning rate.